# Generating Population Density Heat Maps using Gigatrees 5

Tags: gedcom, maps

I've started using Gigatrees 5.08 downloaded from http://timforsythe.com/gigatrees.html  as a tool for sharing information on my family tree research.
I'm very impressed and everything works fine (and it's already found some errors I had missed)
I have the location maps working (so I have got the Google API/Mapquest keys working and the sqlite database that holds the location (gigatrees.sqlite) has been populated)
The build log confirms that coordinate lookup is complete and says that it is generating Distribution Map and then Origin maps.

However the overall Heat Map and individual Origin Maps show no markers (or even a map)

I've looked at the working example that the creator (Tim Forsythe) has made available and I can see that the map.html and then the individual maps\Ixx.html files need to contain the necessary data.
e.g.
var myPinData=[
{lat:37.5841,lng:-122.3660,c:1,i:myImage,t: .........
This data is used by the script gigatrees-maps.js to add all the points to the google map

In the map.html files that are generated for me, there is no definition of the map icons or myPinData.

I've also tried simple 1 family, 3 individual sample.ged - this made no difference.

As a test I also copied the icon setup and a few lat/long points into map.html and this then works fine (so no issues with the Google API)

I'm running gigatrees.exe on Windows 10 (64 bit) with administrator rights

Tim appears to have stopped any further development so it's difficult to find any recent discussion (last topic here was at end of 2017) and I may be out of luck.

Has anyone sucessfully used this final version of Gigatress to generate heat maps?

If so, please can you confirm if the lat/long data is generated as part of the map.html file?

Is there any additional setting needed in the user.xml options file?

Answer (score 2):

Since I posted, the author has added a discussion area on http://timforsythe.com/gigatrees.html where I was able to describe the issue.
Tim Forsythe has very quickly provided an updated version 5.09 that fixes this issue.